# My Timer is not reset when click on reset button C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

initialize the components

System.Timers.Timer t;
int h, m, s;

I want to `reset` the timer when I click on the `reset` button and turn it to `00.00.00`, but when I try to `reset` it with the `code` the timer stops. But when I start the timer and stop it, it doesn't get reset to `00.00.00`

Method of `timer`

```
private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            s += 1;
            if (s == 60)
            {
                s = 0;
                m += 1;
            }
            if (m == 60)
            {
                m = 0;
                h += 1;

            }
            lbltime.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", h.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), 
          m.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), s.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));

        }));
}
```

Form load event

```
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
        t.Start();

       Reset Button Which is not working
        t.Dispose();
```

Comment: You need to reset variables, set them to `0`. `Dispose()` won't do this for you.

Comment: Maybe a [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1) would suit your needs better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => lbltime.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss")));
    }

    private void OnResetButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
    }
```

This uses a stopwatch to measure the time, and a timer to update the label from the stopwatch. This will also be much more accurate since timers do not guarantee any particular tick-frequency.

Comment: Same idea would be to use `DateTime`.